# how to add a dynamic date filter to Access report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am very new to access and vba.

I have created an access database and have created a report. One of the columns in the report is a date column and I want to create a dynamic user filter, where the user can enter the date range and the query would accept that filter.

I am using Access 2013. On the Property Sheet I see a lookup section, where I can chose textbox, listbox, or combo box. I also see a section 'Input mask'. Do I need to use these, and if so, how? Do I need vba code anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can approach this.  Which method depends on factors such as how much data you're moving around.

Example you have a field called ShipDate and you want to see everything that was shipped between June 1 and June 10
Lets assume that `txtStartDate` and `txtEndDate` are textboxes that were filled with the dates

Using `Filter`

```
Reports![MyReportName].RecordSource = "MyQuery"
Reports![MyReportName].Filter = "ShipDate BETWEEN #" & txtStartDate & "# AND #" & txtEndDate & "#"
Reports![MyReportName].FilterOn = True
```

- positive: Only have to change `Filter` and `FilterOn`
- negative: (I may be mistaken on this, hopefully someone will correct me if I am)If the data resides on a network location and not on your desktop, you're really pulling the entire query to your computer and then filtering on your screen.

Editing SQL string

```
strSQL = "SELECT ShipDate FROM MyTable WHERE ShipDate BETWEEN #" & txtStartDate & "# AND #" & txtEndDate & "#"
Reports![MyReportName].RecordSource = strSQL
```

- positive: Only pulls in the absolute bare minimum of records needed to display
- negative: You have to build the query string and set the `RecordSource`

I personally use the filter method until I start using query that return more than couple hundred records.  I have not noticed any significant time differences between the two methods other than when I had a query that was returning around 50k records

Comment: Where exactly does the code for each of your suggestions go? Attached to a 'Filter' button?

Comment: I usually place it "Open Report" button click sub.  Or if you're putting it on the report itself and would like it to update automatically then maybe the Report_Current?  I'm not sure if there is a Report Current event in the same way that there is a Form Current.  You could just have a button that is called refresh and runs this code that is viewable on screen only and wont show up when you print your report.

Comment: So, you can just make a refresh button and use the filter code as shown above? Also, when you wrote .RecordSource = "Myquery", when is that name used and why is it necessary? I don't see "Myquery" being referred to in the following code.

Comment: The benefit of using `Filter` is that you save your query definition and then don't have to edit it.  MyQuery is just the name I used for whatever that query will be.  On the other method, the reason it doesn't appear is because there is no query named MyQuery, you're building the string and then putting that directly into the recordsource.  If I'm not being clear enough let me know.

Comment: To clarify: if you create a RecordSource named MyQuery, now it will show up in the Record Source dropdown on the Property sheet on the Report? Why would this help with editing, you'd still need to go back into the code if you needed to change the filter. The only benifit I see is if you wanted to reuse the record source for another report, but is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I normally create a form that contains any dynamic info the user can add.  Even if it's just a single date field, that's OK.

The query behind the report will contain the date field you're using, and in the Criteria you can put

```
=[Forms]![MyFormName]![MyTextBoxName]
```

Where MyFormName is the name of the form mentioned above, and MyTextboxName is the name of the textbox that the user puts the date in.

Then put a button on the form that opens the report.  Done!

Comment: I understand. But I really would like to have the filter option on the report itself. That way, if the user changed his mind on the date selection, he wouldn't need to go back to the original form to enter the new date data...